# How to scale edge length and keep layout of edge-weighted Graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I love using `Graph` as structure to store and visualize my data in *Mathematica*. Consider the following simple example for creating a `Graph` object with weighted directed edges. I already laid out the graph in a tree structure using the options `{"LayeredEmbedding", "Orientation" -> Top, "RootVertex" -> 1}` I found in the documentation of [`GraphLayout`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GraphLayout.html), since this representation is useful for my particular needs.

```
vertices={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100};
edges={1\[DirectedEdge]2,3\[DirectedEdge]4,5\[DirectedEdge]6,7\[DirectedEdge]8,9\[DirectedEdge]10,11\[DirectedEdge]12,13\[DirectedEdge]14,15\[DirectedEdge]16,17\[DirectedEdge]18,19\[DirectedEdge]20,21\[DirectedEdge]22,23\[DirectedEdge]24,25\[DirectedEdge]26,27\[DirectedEdge]28,29\[DirectedEdge]30,31\[DirectedEdge]32,33\[DirectedEdge]34,35\[DirectedEdge]36,37\[DirectedEdge]38,39\[DirectedEdge]40,41\[DirectedEdge]42,43\[DirectedEdge]44,45\[DirectedEdge]46,47\[DirectedEdge]48,49\[DirectedEdge]50,51\[DirectedEdge]52,53\[DirectedEdge]54,57\[DirectedEdge]58,59\[DirectedEdge]60,61\[DirectedEdge]62,63\[DirectedEdge]64,65\[DirectedEdge]66,67\[DirectedEdge]68,69\[DirectedEdge]70,71\[DirectedEdge]72,73\[DirectedEdge]74,75\[DirectedEdge]76,77\[DirectedEdge]78,79\[DirectedEdge]80,81\[DirectedEdge]82,83\[DirectedEdge]84,85\[DirectedEdge]86,87\[DirectedEdge]88,89\[DirectedEdge]90,91\[DirectedEdge]92,93\[DirectedEdge]94,95\[DirectedEdge]96,97\[DirectedEdge]98,99\[DirectedEdge]100,2\[DirectedEdge]3,2\[DirectedEdge]5,6\[DirectedEdge]7,6\[DirectedEdge]9,10\[DirectedEdge]11,10\[DirectedEdge]13,14\[DirectedEdge]15,14\[DirectedEdge]17,4\[DirectedEdge]19,4\[DirectedEdge]21,22\[DirectedEdge]23,22\[DirectedEdge]25,20\[DirectedEdge]27,20\[DirectedEdge]29,28\[DirectedEdge]31,28\[DirectedEdge]33,34\[DirectedEdge]35,34\[DirectedEdge]37,30\[DirectedEdge]39,30\[DirectedEdge]41,42\[DirectedEdge]43,42\[DirectedEdge]45,40\[DirectedEdge]47,40\[DirectedEdge]49,24\[DirectedEdge]51,24\[DirectedEdge]53,54\[DirectedEdge]55,54\[DirectedEdge]56,26\[DirectedEdge]57,26\[DirectedEdge]59,60\[DirectedEdge]61,60\[DirectedEdge]63,58\[DirectedEdge]65,58\[DirectedEdge]67,8\[DirectedEdge]69,8\[DirectedEdge]71,72\[DirectedEdge]73,72\[DirectedEdge]75,76\[DirectedEdge]77,76\[DirectedEdge]79,74\[DirectedEdge]81,74\[DirectedEdge]83,70\[DirectedEdge]85,70\[DirectedEdge]87,88\[DirectedEdge]89,88\[DirectedEdge]91,86\[DirectedEdge]93,86\[DirectedEdge]95,12\[DirectedEdge]97,12\[DirectedEdge]99};
weights={18,53,50,53,51,96,129,47,47,55,68,75,74,82,65,87,76,10,10,57,99,4,4,46,46,81,81,64,74,7,7,17,17,61,86,64,70,17,17,23,23,64,104,8,8,48,48,80,80,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};

Graph[vertices, edges, EdgeWeight -> weights, 
  EdgeLabels -> MapThread[Rule, {edges, weights}], 
  GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding", "Orientation" -> Top, 
    "RootVertex" -> 1}, EdgeLabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, 20]]
```

The graph that I get with these options looks like the following:

[image]

Edge weights are put as labels but all edges have the same length due to the options specified. What I would like to obtain now is a `Graph` object with edges scaled according to the edge weight while keeping the tree-like layout of the graph. I have read the documentation of `GraphLayout` and several other documentation pages on `EdgeWeight`, `TreeGraph`, *etc*. The only possibility I found so far is to use the options `{"SpringElectricalEmbedding", "EdgeWeighted"->True}` for the `Graph` object. However this destroys the tree-like layout I want to keep:

```
 Graph[vertices, edges, EdgeWeight -> weights, 
 EdgeLabels -> MapThread[Rule, {edges, weights}], 
 GraphLayout -> {"SpringElectricalEmbedding", "EdgeWeighted" -> True},EdgeLabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, 20]]
```

And the `Graph` object looks like this:

[image]

**Question: Is there a way to combine the tree-like layout of `Graph` with weight-scaled edges in Mathematica?**

I think one would have to change the `VertexCoordinates` that are embedded in the `Graph`. It is easy to access the current `VertexCoordinates` using `GraphEmbedding` but I can't figure out how to change them appropriately.

Comment: To my knowledge only `SpringEmbedding` and `SpringElectricalEmbedding ` take `EdgeWeighted`. More details here: [**Graphs with weight in 2D and 3D**](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/29180)

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov: Thanks for the hint. I also found the option `{"SpringElectricalEmbedding", EdgeWeighted"->True}` for `GraphLayout` (see second graph above). But, I would like to keep a tree-like structure of the `Graph` while using the edge weights.

Comment: Nice idea, but this might be a difficult feature to add: suppose your  53->55 was 'length' 1, and 53->68 was 167 - the graph would become unusable almost immediately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like you mention, you could try to modify existing coordinates.  Since your graph is tree, BreadthFirstScan can be used to search a graph and update coordinates.

What I did is to keep accumulating weights based on dfs and adding or replace those value to only y-coordinates of the existing coordinates (updating x coordinate could mess up tree structure easily, so I didn't try that).

```
g = Graph[vertices, edges, EdgeWeight -> weights, 
  EdgeLabels -> MapThread[Rule, {edges, weights}], 
  GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding", "Orientation" -> Top, 
    "RootVertex" -> 1}, EdgeLabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, 20], 
   VertexLabels -> "Name"];

coords = GraphEmbedding[g];
update[1] = 0;
BreadthFirstScan[g, 1,
  "DiscoverVertex" -> (w = PropertyValue[{g, #2 \[DirectedEdge] #1}, EdgeWeight];
   If[NumberQ[w], update[#1] = update[#2] + w]; &)];

add = update /@ VertexList[g];
{x, y} = Transpose[coords];
y = y - add/50;
ncoord1 = Transpose[{x, y}];
ncoord2 = Transpose[{x,-add/25}];

SetProperty[g, VertexCoordinates -> ncoord1]
```

[image]

```
SetProperty[g, VertexCoordinates -> ncoord2]
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting approach, thanks very much! The problem I see is that the edges are indeed scaled by some factor, but it doesn't directly represent the edge weights that are written on the edges. Look at the lower part (vertices 65,67,61,63 to 66,68,62,64) for example. There you have edges with weights 17 and 7, respectively. But, the edge length looks about the same whereas the difference is 10. The left edges should therefore be at least twice as long.

Comment: @g3kk0 That's why I put two different ncoords. Try ncoord2.

Comment: Thanks for that information and the edit. This looks just like what I was looking for ;)