# Scaling the edge length of a graph to be equal to edge weight

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, graphics3d, import

I've imported a dxf file in Mathematica

```
dxf = Import["input.dxf"]
```

The following graph is present in the dxf file available [here](https://github.com/DeepaMahm/misc/blob/master/input.dxf).
[image]

The actual dimensions don't match the value displayed in the text label (in yellow) over the lines. For instance, 62 is the value displayed and 54.0833 is the actual dimension. And I want to rescale the actual lengths to the values displayed in yellow-colored label over the lines.

I understand the coordinates displayed in the input provided above have to be varied. Probably, the first coordinate can be fixed and the subsequent coordinates can be shifted.

I found a similar post [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29374/how-to-scale-edge-length-and-keep-layout-of-edge-weighted-graph) and I would like to try the solution posted there (also added below).

```
g = Graph[vertices, edges, EdgeWeight -> weights, 
  EdgeLabels -> MapThread[Rule, {edges, weights}], 
  GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding", "Orientation" -> Top, 
    "RootVertex" -> 1}, EdgeLabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, 20], 
   VertexLabels -> "Name"];

coords = GraphEmbedding[g];
update[1] = 0;
BreadthFirstScan[g, 1,
  "DiscoverVertex" -> (w = PropertyValue[{g, #2 \[DirectedEdge] #1}, EdgeWeight];
   If[NumberQ[w], update[#1] = update[#2] + w]; &)];

add = update /@ VertexList[g];
{x, y} = Transpose[coords];
y = y - add/50;
ncoord1 = Transpose[{x, y}];
ncoord2 = Transpose[{x,-add/25}];

SetProperty[g, VertexCoordinates -> ncoord1]
```

To try the above solution on the imported dxf, first I have to convert the dxf into a graph object after import.
I am not sure how to convert dxf to graph object in Mathematica and I'd also like to know if the solution provided in the above-mentioned post can be used for my input.

Any suggestions on how to proceed will be really helpful.

EDIT: I'm trying to clarify here

[image]

What do I want to achieve?

Example:
Actual edge length between nodes 7 and 6 : computed as euclidean distance between the coordinates of 7 and 6 is 54.08.

I want to scale this length to 62.

EDIT2: Adding additional details

If one directly loads the input file in AutoCAD, the yellow text displayed in the following image is the actual dimensions[image]

And I want to convert the dimensions to the corresponding yellow labels displayed in the following image:
[image]

Addressing the following comment

> It seems that the DXF file was saved in a perspective view, and that's
>   why none of the edge labels match the lengths of the corresponding
>   lines

The labels displayed in the second image in EDIT2 were altered externally using an AutoLISP code to merely show how the actual lengths of the corresponding lines have to be scaled. In the first image displayed in EDIT2, the edge labels exactly match the lengths of the corresponding lines.

Comment: I'm confused. DXF stores geometrical information, not a graph. Don't you just want to rescale the whole thing proportionally?

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes you are absolutely right and thanks for correcting the terminology that I use. It's the geometry that is stored in DXF. I did try the re-scale option that you are referring to. The problem is it rescales the whole geometry and what I want to do with the geometry is to scale just the edges (if I may call the geometry as **graph**).

Comment: I came across the post [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29374/how-to-scale-edge-length-and-keep-layout-of-edge-weighted-graph) and was wondering if I could try a similar approach. i.e import the geometry from dxf, convert to a graph, and scale the edge lengths to edge weights (i.e. yellow labels in dxf).

Comment: I do not understand what you are saying. There is nothing but edges in this drawing. You should at least upload that file somewhere, and explain in more detail what the problem is.

Comment: @Szabolcs I have already shared the link to input file in my original post. I am sharing it again [link](https://github.com/DeepaMahm/misc/blob/master/input.dxf)

Comment: Please check my edit and kindly let me know if it is still unclear

Comment: @Szabolcs I have added a second edit. I think now it would be clear. If not, please let me know

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
{dxf, edges, vd} = Import["(...path...)/input.dxf", #] & /@ 
   {"Graphics3D", "LineData", "VertexData"};

edges = UndirectedEdge @@@ edges;
```

gives

```
dxf = Graphics3D[{{EdgeForm[], {RGBColor[0., 0., 0.], 
 {Text[StyleForm["1", FontColor -> RGBColor[1., 0., 0.]], {75., 25., 0.}, {0, 0}], 
  Text[StyleForm["2", FontColor -> RGBColor[1., 0., 0.]], {115., 45., 0.}, {0, 0}], 
  Text[StyleForm["3", FontColor -> RGBColor[1., 0., 0.]], {90., 60., 0.}, {0, 0}], 
  Text[StyleForm["4", FontColor -> RGBColor[1., 0., 0.]], {10., 5., 0.}, {0, 0}], 
  Text[StyleForm["5", FontColor -> RGBColor[1., 0., 0.]], {45., 0., 0.}, {0, 0}], 
  Text[StyleForm["6", FontColor -> RGBColor[1., 0., 0.]], {45., 55., 0.}, {0, 0}], 
  Text[StyleForm["7", FontColor -> RGBColor[1., 0., 0.]], {0., 25., 0.}, {0, 0}], 
  Text[StyleForm["8", FontColor -> RGBColor[1., 0., 0.]], {10., 50., 0.}, {0, 0}], 
  Text[StyleForm["9", FontColor -> RGBColor[1., 0., 0.]], {115., 25., 0.}, {0, 0}], 
  {RGBColor[0., 0., 0.], Line[{{75., 25., 0.}, {115., 45., 0.}}]}, 
  Text[StyleForm["49.6", FontColor -> RGBColor[1., 1., 0.]], {95., 35., 0.}, {0, 0}], 
  {RGBColor[0., 0., 0.], Line[{{75., 25., 0.}, {10., 5., 0.}}]}, 
  Text[StyleForm["74.4", FontColor -> RGBColor[1., 1., 0.]], {42.5, 15., 0.}, {0, 0}], 
  {RGBColor[0., 0., 0.], Line[{{75., 25., 0.}, {45., 0., 0.}}]}, 
  Text[StyleForm["49.6", FontColor -> RGBColor[1., 1., 0.]], {60., 12.5, 0.}, {0, 0}], 
  {RGBColor[0., 0., 0.],  Line[{{115., 45., 0.}, {90., 60., 0.}}]}, 
  Text[StyleForm["37.2", FontColor -> RGBColor[1., 1., 0.]], {102.5, 52.5, 0.}, {0, 0}],
  {RGBColor[0., 0., 0.], Line[{{115., 45., 0.}, {45., 55., 0.}}]}, 
  Text[StyleForm["74.4", FontColor -> RGBColor[1., 1., 0.]], {80., 50., 0.}, {0, 0}], 
  {RGBColor[0., 0., 0.], Line[{{90., 60., 0.}, {45., 55., 0.}}]}, 
  Text[StyleForm["49.6", FontColor -> RGBColor[1., 1., 0.]], {67.5, 57.5, 0.}, {0, 0}], 
  {RGBColor[0., 0., 0.], Line[{{10., 5., 0.}, {45., 0., 0.}}]}, 
  Text[StyleForm["37.2", FontColor -> RGBColor[1., 1., 0.]], {27.5, 2.5, 0.}, {0, 0}], 
 {RGBColor[0., 0., 0.], Line[{{10., 5., 0.}, {0., 25., 0.}}]}, 
  Text[StyleForm["24.8", FontColor -> RGBColor[1., 1., 0.]], {5., 15., 0.}, {0, 0}],
 {RGBColor[0., 0., 0.], Line[{{45., 55., 0.}, {0., 25., 0.}}]}, 
  Text[StyleForm["62", FontColor -> RGBColor[1., 1., 0.]], {22.5, 40., 0.}, {0, 0}], 
 {RGBColor[0., 0., 0.], Line[{{0., 25., 0.}, {10., 50., 0.}}]}, 
  Text[StyleForm["37.2", FontColor -> RGBColor[1., 1., 0.]], {5., 37.5, 0.}, {0, 0}], 
  {RGBColor[0., 0., 0.], Line[{{115., 45., 0.}, {115., 25., 0.}}]}, 
  Text[StyleForm["24.8", FontColor -> RGBColor[1., 1., 0.]], {115., 35., 0.}, 
    {0, 0}]}}}, {EdgeForm[], {RGBColor[0., 0., 0.], {}}}}, 
  Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

```
edges = {1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 4, 2 <-> 5, 2 <-> 6, 5 <-> 6, 
   3 <-> 4, 3 <-> 7, 6 <-> 7, 7 <-> 8, 2 <-> 9};

vd = {{75., 25., 0}, {115., 45., 0}, {10., 5., 0}, {45., 0, 0}, 
  {90., 60., 0}, {45., 55., 0}, {0, 25., 0}, {10., 50., 0}, {115.,  25.,0}};

vl = Range[Length@vd];

vcoords = MapIndexed[#2[[1]] -> # &, vd];
ew = # -> ToExpression[#2] & @@@ 
   Partition[Cases[Replace[dxf, {_, Line[x_]} :>  UndirectedEdge @@ 
    (Replace[Round@x, KeyMap[Round][Association[Reverse /@ vcoords]], All]), 
      All], {___, p : PatternSequence[_UndirectedEdge, _Text] ..} :> 
      Sequence @@ ({p} /. Text[t_, ___] :> t[[1]]), All], 2];

g3d = Graph3D[vl, edges, VertexCoordinates -> vcoords, 
  EdgeWeight -> ew, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
  EdgeLabels -> {e_ :> Placed["EdgeWeight", Center]}, 
  VertexSize -> .3, VertexStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

```
Graph[vl, edges, VertexCoordinates -> {v_ :> vd[[v, ;; 2]]}, 
 EdgeWeight -> ew, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
 EdgeLabels -> {e_ :> Placed["EdgeWeight", .5]}, VertexSize -> .3, 
 VertexStyle -> Red, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

**1.** `GraphLayout -> {"SpringElectricalEmbedding", "EdgeWeighted" -> True}`:

```
Graph[vl, edges, 
 GraphLayout -> {"SpringElectricalEmbedding", "EdgeWeighted" -> True}, 
 EdgeWeight -> ew, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
 EdgeLabels -> {e_ :> Placed["EdgeWeight", .5]}, VertexSize -> .3, 
 VertexStyle -> Red, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
Graph3D[vl, edges, 
 GraphLayout -> {"SpringElectricalEmbedding", "EdgeWeighted" -> True},
 EdgeWeight -> ew, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
 EdgeLabels -> {e_ :> Placed["EdgeWeight", .5]}, VertexSize -> .3, 
 VertexStyle -> Red, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

**2.** Use `NMinimize` to get the vertex coordinates:

```
vars = Array[Through[{x, y} @ #] &, Length @ vd];

λ = 1.;
obj = Total[(Norm[vars[[First@#]] - vars[[Last@#]]] - # /. ew)^2 & /@ EdgeList[g3d]] + 
    λ Total[Norm /@ (vars - vd[[All, ;; 2]])];

lbnd = 0;
ubnd = 500;

solution = Last@Minimize[{obj, And @@ Thread[lbnd <= Join @@ vars <= ubnd]}, 
    Join @@ vars];

edgeLengths = # -> Norm[Through[{x, y}@First[#]] - Through[{x, y}@Last[#]]] /. 
     solution & /@ EdgeList[g3d];

Grid[Prepend[{#, # /. ew, # /. edgeLengths} & /@ 
   EdgeList[g3d], {"edge", "EdgeWeight", "Edge Length"}], 
 Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

```
Graph[vl, edges, 
 VertexCoordinates -> {v_ :> ({x[v], y[v]} /. solution)}, 
 EdgeWeight -> ew, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
 EdgeLabels -> {e_ :> Placed["EdgeWeight", .3]}, VertexSize -> .7, 
 VertexStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

**Note:** You can play with different values for `λ` to weight the two terms in the objective function differently. You may have to play with different values for the bounds `lbnd` and `ubnd` in case `NMinimize` gives an error/warning message.

**Update:** We can use the same approach to get 3D vertex coordinates:

```
vars3d = Array[Through[{x, y, z}@#] &, Length @ vd];

λ = 1/100.;

obj3d = Total[(Norm[vars3d[[First@#]] - vars3d[[Last@#]]] - # /. ew)^2 & /@ 
  EdgeList[g3d]] +  λ Total[Norm /@ (vars3d - vd)];

lbnd = 0;
ubnd = 500;

solution3d = Last@Minimize[{obj3d, And @@ Thread[lbnd <= Join @@ vars3d <= ubnd]}, 
    Join @@ vars3d];

edgeLengths3d = # -> Norm[vars3d[[First@#]] - vars3d[[Last@#]]] /. 
     solution3d & /@ EdgeList[g3d];

Grid[Prepend[{#, # /. ew, # /. edgeLengths3d} & /@ 
   EdgeList[g3d], {"edge", "EdgeWeight", "Edge Length"}], 
 Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

```
Graph3D[vl, edges, 
 VertexCoordinates -> {v_ :> ({x[v], y[v], z[v]} /. solution3d)}, 
 EdgeWeight -> ew, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
 EdgeLabels -> {e_ :> Placed["EdgeWeight", .5]}, VertexSize -> .3, 
 VertexStyle -> Red, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Just a small request, can we avoid displaying the completepath to the github link in the answer provided? Could you please modify it to `input.dxf`?

Comment: The solution that you have provided is good. But my only concern is the coordinates of the vertices have shift drastically. From what I understand this is due to vertex coordinates given as outputs by the optimization task after minimizing the cost function. But can we impose additional constraints to restrict the movement of the vertex coordinates around the neighbourhood of the coordinates in the original input (i.e input.dxf)?

Comment: Brilliant! Could you please suggest how to export this back in dxf format?

Comment: Is it possible to automate this step where we specify the edges?`edges = {1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 4, 2 <-> 5, 2 <-> 6, 5 <-> 6, 
   3 <-> 4, 3 <-> 7, 6 <-> 7, 7 <-> 8, 2 <-> 9};` I think this is where the  other test case fails

Comment: @Natasha, for specifying edges, you can use `edges = UndirectedEdge @@@ Import["input.dxf", "LineData"];`  Re "Unable to find a point..."  you can play with the hard-coded  lower and upper bounds (`0` and `500`) for the decision variables.  And for exporting, try `Export["filename.dxf", Show[Graph3D[g]]]` where `g` is the output from `Graph[vl, edges,...]` or from `Graph3D[vl, edges,...]`.

Comment: Could you please add a few comment lines in the code?  I'd like to share an update on the other test case,  Re "Unable to find a point..." got resolved. Thank you very much.

Comment: `Export["fle.dxf", Show[Graph3D[g]]]` exports it successfully. But this file is not loadable is softwares like AutoCAD . There appears to be a problem with export

Comment: Could you please explain what the first and second term in the objective function does? I'm sorry, but I am really trying to understand what goes on in the code so that I can alter the parameters and get it working for the other test cases. Also, please explain on which variable the  upper and lower bounds are imposed

Comment: @Natasha,   the first term in the objective function is sum of squared deviations of edge lengths from the desired lengths and the second term is the sum of squared deviations of vertex positions from the initial vertex positions.

Comment: Could you please check this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/225891/scaling-the-edge-length-of-a-graph-to-be-equal-to-edge-weight-again)?

Answer (score 2):

No solution  yet, but here's a way to get data from the DXF file for a start, including making a graph from the DXF edges and vertices.

I think the best approach to reproduce the labeled edge values is transform the vertex coordinates to undo the effect of perspective.

Start with `Import`, then click on the `dxf` mesh region. Use `View Options` to select the `Top` view, and `Mesh Decoration` to select `Show edge labels` and `Show vertex labels`.

[image: region mesh]

Notice that the vertex numbers are different than your image. Use the edge numbers from the mesh region to match the edge labels from your image. For example, edge 9 is 62.

```
labels={49.6,74.4,49.6,37.2,74.4,49.6,28.4,24.8,62,37.2,24.8};
```

Use `Import["input.dxf", "Graphics3D"]` to a get rotatable graphics version of the DXF file that shows the labeled edges and vertices. You can get the vertex coordinates and other data from the DXF file like this:

```
vp = Import["input.dxf", "ViewPoint"];
lo = Import["input.dxf", "LineObjects"];
ld = Import["input.dxf", "LineData"];(*vertex numbers at line end-points*)
vd = Import["input.dxf", "VertexData"];(*vertex coordinates*)
```

For testing, when you have new, transformed vertex coordinates, you can make line objects from the new vertex coordinates with `lines=Line[vdNew[[#]]]&/@ld`, then check the new line lengths with `ArcLength/@lines`.

It seems that the DXF file was saved in a perspective view, and that's why none of the edge labels match the lengths of the corresponding lines.

```
edgeData = Transpose@{Range[Length[lo]], labels, ArcLength /@ lo};
TableForm[SortBy[edgeData, {#[[2 ;; 3]]} &], 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"Edge", "Labels", "Length"}}]
```

> ```
> Edge  Labels  Length
> 11    24.8    20.
> 8     24.8    22.3607
> 7     28.4    35.3553
> 10    37.2    26.9258
> 4     37.2    29.1548
> 3     49.6    39.0512
> 1     49.6    44.7214
> 6     49.6    45.2769
> 9     62      54.0833
> 2     74.4    68.0074
> 5     74.4    70.7107
> ```

Here's a basic graph, using line data, `ld`, and weights for each edge.

```
ew = Normal@AssociationThread[UndirectedEdge @@@ ld, labels];
g = Graph[Sort[UndirectedEdge @@@ ld], VertexLabels -> Automatic, 
  EdgeLabels -> Automatic, EdgeWeight -> ew]
```

[image: graph of DXF edges and vertices]

Is think this gives you a some data to work with.

Comment: @creidhe Thanks a lot for the response . Could you please check EDIT2?