# Scaling the edge length of a graph to be equal to edge weight (again)

Tags: graphs-and-networks, graphics3d, mathematical-optimization

This is a follow up to my previous question posted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220334/scaling-the-edge-length-of-a-graph-to-be-equal-to-edge-weight)

The following is an excerpt of the solution provided [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/220576/58343) to set the edge length of a graph equal to the edge weights

```
edges = {1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 4, 2 <-> 5, 2 <-> 6, 5 <-> 6, 
   3 <-> 4, 3 <-> 7, 6 <-> 7, 7 <-> 8, 2 <-> 9};

vd = {{75., 25., 0}, {115., 45., 0}, {10., 5., 0}, {45., 0, 0}, 
  {90., 60., 0}, {45., 55., 0}, {0, 25., 0}, {10., 50., 0}, {115.,  25.,0}};

vl = Range[Length@vd];

vcoords = MapIndexed[#2[[1]] -> # &, vd];
ew = {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2 -> 49.6, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3 -> 74.4, 
 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 4 -> 49.6, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 5 -> 37.2, 
 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 6 -> 74.4, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 6 -> 49.6, 
 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4 -> 37.2, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 7 -> 24.8, 
 6 \[UndirectedEdge] 7 -> 62, 7 \[UndirectedEdge] 8 -> 37.2, 
 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 9 -> 24.8}

g3d = Graph3D[vl, edges, VertexCoordinates -> vcoords, 
  EdgeWeight -> ew, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
  EdgeLabels -> {e_ :> Placed["EdgeWeight", Center]}, 
  VertexSize -> .3, VertexStyle -> Red]
vars3d = Array[Through[{x, y, z}@#] &, Length @ vd];

λ = 1/100.;

obj3d = Total[(Norm[vars3d[[First@#]] - vars3d[[Last@#]]] - # /. ew)^2 & /@ 
  EdgeList[g3d]] +  λ Total[Norm /@ (vars3d - vd)];

lbnd = 0;
ubnd = 500;

solution3d = Last@Minimize[{obj3d, And @@ Thread[lbnd <= Join @@ vars3d <= ubnd]}, 
    Join @@ vars3d];

edgeLengths3d = # -> Norm[vars3d[[First@#]] - vars3d[[Last@#]]] /. 
     solution3d & /@ EdgeList[g3d];

Grid[Prepend[{#, # /. ew, # /. edgeLengths3d} & /@ 
   EdgeList[g3d], {"edge", "EdgeWeight", "Edge Length"}], 
 Dividers -> All]
```

I would like to know how to modify the above when the nodes of the graph aren't numbered consecutively.

I tried the following,

```
edges = {1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 4, 2 <-> 11, 2 <-> 6, 11 <-> 6, 
   3 <-> 4, 3 <-> 7, 6 <-> 7, 7 <-> 8, 2 <-> 10};
vd = {{75., 25., 0}, {115., 45., 0}, {10., 5., 0}, {45., 0, 0}, {90., 
    60., 0}, {45., 55., 0}, {0, 25., 0}, {10., 50., 0}, {115., 25., 
    0}};

vl = {1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 6, 7, 8, 10};

vcoords = Thread[vl -> vd];

ew = {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2 -> 49.6`, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3 -> 74.4`, 
  1 \[UndirectedEdge] 4 -> 49.6`, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 11 -> 37.2`, 
  2 \[UndirectedEdge] 6 -> 74.4`, 11 \[UndirectedEdge] 6 -> 49.6`, 
  3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4 -> 37.2`, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 7 -> 24.8`, 
  6 \[UndirectedEdge] 7 -> 62, 7 \[UndirectedEdge] 8 -> 37.2`, 
  2 \[UndirectedEdge] 10 -> 24.8`};

g3d = Graph3D[vl, edges, VertexCoordinates -> vcoords, 
  EdgeWeight -> ew, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
  EdgeLabels -> {e_ :> Placed["EdgeWeight", Center]}, 
  VertexSize -> .3, VertexStyle -> Red]

vars3d = Array[Through@{x, y, z}@vl[[#]] &, Length@vl];

λ = 1/100.;

obj3d = Total[(Norm[vars3d[[First@#]] - vars3d[[Last@#]]] - # /. 
         ew)^2 & /@ EdgeList[g3d]] + \[Lambda] Total[
     Norm /@ (vars3d - vd)];
```

I couldn't execute `obj3d` successfully, the following is displayed

```
Part::partw: Part 11 of {{x[1],y[1],z[1]},{x[2],y[2],z[2]},{x[3],y[3],z[3]},{x[4],y[4],z[4]},{x[11],y[11],z[11]},{x[6],y[6],z[6]},{x[7],y[7],z[7]},{x[8],y[8],z[8]},{x[10],y[10],z[10]}} does not exist.
```

Suggestions on how to modify the expression for `obj3d` and the lines below it to successfully use the
solution provided in the previous post for the new input will be highly appreciated.

[Notebook](https://github.com/DeepaMahm/misc/blob/master/so_14_7_20.nb)

EDIT:
The suggestion provided below resolved the error reported above. Next, I did the same modification for line

```
edgeLengths3d = # -> 
Norm[[Through@{x, y, z}@First[#] -  Through@{x, y, z}@Last[#]]] /. solution3d & /@ EdgeList[g3d];
```

and the following error occurs

```
Part::pkspec1: The expression {x[1]-x[2],y[1]-y[2],z[1]-z[2]} cannot be used as a part specification.
```

Could you please suggest how this line has to be modified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the definition of `obj3d` to

```
obj3dB = Total[(Norm[Through @ {x, y, z} @ First[#] - 
           Through@{x, y, z} @ Last[#]] - # /. ew)^2 & /@ EdgeList[g3d]] + 
    λ Total[Norm /@ (vars3d - vd)]
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped. I tried to make the same change `edgeLengths3d = # -> 
Norm[[Through@{x, y, z}@First[#] -  Through@{x, y, z}@Last[#]]] /. solution3d & /@ EdgeList[g3d];` and the following error occurs `Part::pkspec1: The expression {x[1]-x[2],y[1]-y[2],z[1]-z[2]} cannot be used as a part specification.` Could you please suggest how this line has to be modified?

Comment: @Natasha, change  `Norm[[Through...]]` to `Norm[Through...]`

Comment: Ahh, thanks. That was my mistake.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit on how to decide on the values of upper bound and lower bound? For one problem, it worked when lbnd = 0 and ubnd = 500; for another it worked when lbnd = 0 and ubnd = 3500. I'm not sure on what basis this range can be set