# How to use Mathematica from Python

Tags: interoperability, python

I've been using the following lines of code to generate 3D geometry ([ref](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220334/scaling-the-edge-length-of-a-graph-to-be-equal-to-edge-weight)).
The inputs `edges`, `vd`, `vl` and `ew` come from Python in the following formats

```
edges = [(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,5), (2,6), (5,6), (3,4), (3,7), (6,7), (7,8), (2,9)];
vl = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
ew = {(1, 2) : 49.6, (1,3): 74.4, (1, 4) : 49.6, (2,5): 37.2, (2, 6) : 74.4, (5, 6): 49.6, 
     (3, 4) : 37.2, (3, 7):24.8, (6, 7) : 62, (7, 8) : 37.2, (2, 9) : 24.8}
vd = {1:[75., 25., 0], 2:[115., 45., 0], 3:[10., 5., 0], 4:[45., 0, 0], 
      5:[90., 60., 0], 6:[45., 55., 0], 7:[0, 25., 0], 8:[10., 50., 0], 9:[115.,  25.,0]};
```

I manually convert the above to the input formats used in Mathematica. I'd like to know how to avoid this manual conversion and directly integrate and run the Mathematica code from Python.

```
edges = {1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 4, 2 <-> 5, 2 <-> 6, 5 <-> 6, 
   3 <-> 4, 3 <-> 7, 6 <-> 7, 7 <-> 8, 2 <-> 9};

vd = {{75., 25., 0}, {115., 45., 0}, {10., 5., 0}, {45., 0, 0}, 
  {90., 60., 0}, {45., 55., 0}, {0, 25., 0}, {10., 50., 0}, {115.,  25.,0}};

vl = Range[Length@vd];

vcoords = MapIndexed[#2[[1]] -> # &, vd];
ew = {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2 -> 49.6, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3 -> 74.4, 
 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 4 -> 49.6, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 5 -> 37.2, 
 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 6 -> 74.4, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 6 -> 49.6, 
 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4 -> 37.2, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 7 -> 24.8, 
 6 \[UndirectedEdge] 7 -> 62, 7 \[UndirectedEdge] 8 -> 37.2, 
 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 9 -> 24.8}

g3d = Graph3D[vl, edges, VertexCoordinates -> vcoords, 
  EdgeWeight -> ew, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
  EdgeLabels -> {e_ :> Placed["EdgeWeight", Center]}, 
  VertexSize -> .3, VertexStyle -> Red]
vars3d = Array[Through[{x, y, z}@#] &, Length @ vd];

λ = 1/100.;

obj3d = Total[(Norm[vars3d[[First@#]] - vars3d[[Last@#]]] - # /. ew)^2 & /@ 
  EdgeList[g3d]] +  λ Total[Norm /@ (vars3d - vd)];

lbnd = 0;
ubnd = 500;

solution3d = Last@Minimize[{obj3d, And @@ Thread[lbnd <= Join @@ vars3d <= ubnd]}, 
    Join @@ vars3d];

edgeLengths3d = # -> Norm[vars3d[[First@#]] - vars3d[[Last@#]]] /. 
     solution3d & /@ EdgeList[g3d];

Grid[Prepend[{#, # /. ew, # /. edgeLengths3d} & /@ 
   EdgeList[g3d], {"edge", "EdgeWeight", "Edge Length"}], 
 Dividers -> All]
```

Suggestions on how to proceed and interface Mathematica from Python will be really helpful.

EDIT: The answer posted below helps in passing input arguments from Python using `PythonExpression`. Next, I would like to evalute these Mathematica expressions from a python script.
Based on the comments below, I installed wolframclient and did the following

```
from wolframclient.evaluation import WolframLanguageSession
session = WolframLanguageSession()
from wolframclient.language import wlexpr
session.evaluate(wlexpr('')) # I would like to know how to inclide Mathematica expressions here
```

EDIT2: Can I do

```
session.evaluate(wlexpr(
'edges = {1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 4, 2 <-> 5, 2 <-> 6, 5 <-> 6, 3 <-> 4, 3 <-> 7, 6 <-> 7, 7 <-> 8, 2 <-> 9};'

'vd = {{75., 25., 0}, {115., 45., 0}, {10., 5., 0}, {45., 0, 0},{90., 60., 0}, {45., 55., 0}, {0, 25., 0}, {10., 50., 0}, {115.,  25.,0}};'

'vl = Range[Length@vd];'))
```

I tried,

```
from wolframclient.evaluation import WolframLanguageSession
session = WolframLanguageSession()
from wolframclient.language import wlexpr


session.evaluate(wlexpr(
'edges = {1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 4, 2 <-> 5, 2 <-> 6, 5 <-> 6, 3 <-> 4, 3 <-> 7, 6 <-> 7, 7 <-> 8, 2 <-> 9};'

'vd = {{75., 25., 0}, {115., 45., 0}, {10., 5., 0}, {45., 0, 0},{90., 60., 0}, {45., 55., 0}, {0, 25., 0}, {10., 50., 0}, {115.,  25.,0}};'

'vl = Range[Length@vd];'
'vcoords = MapIndexed[#2[[1]] -> # &, vd];'
'ew = {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2 -> 49.6, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3 -> 74.4,'
'1 \[UndirectedEdge] 4 -> 49.6, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 5 -> 37.2,'
'2 \[UndirectedEdge] 6 -> 74.4, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 6 -> 49.6,'
'3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4 -> 37.2, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 7 -> 24.8,'
'6 \[UndirectedEdge] 7 -> 62, 7 \[UndirectedEdge] 8 -> 37.2,'
'2 \[UndirectedEdge] 9 -> 24.8};'

'g3d = Graph3D[vl, edges, VertexCoordinates -> vcoords,EdgeWeight -> ew, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center],'
'EdgeLabels -> {e_ :> Placed["EdgeWeight", Center]},'
'VertexSize -> .3, VertexStyle -> Red];'

'vars3d = Array[Through[{x, y, z}@#] &, Length @ vd];'
'λ = 1/100.;'
'obj3d = Total[(Norm[vars3d[[First@#]] - vars3d[[Last@#]]] - # /. ew)^2 & /@EdgeList[g3d]] +  λ Total[Norm /@ (vars3d - vd)];'
'lbnd = 0;'
'ubnd = 500;'

'solution3d = Last@Minimize[{obj3d, And @@ Thread[lbnd <= Join @@ vars3d <= ubnd]},Join @@ vars3d];'

'edgeLengths3d = # -> Norm[vars3d[[First@#]] - vars3d[[Last@#]]] /.solution3d & /@ EdgeList[g3d];'

'Grid[Prepend[{#, # /. ew, # /. edgeLengths3d} & /@EdgeList[g3d], {"edge", "EdgeWeight", "Edge Length"}],Dividers -> All];'

'z1 = Values[solution3d] // Partition[#, 3] &;'

'theFile = File["op.txt"];'

'Export[theFile, z1, "Table"];'
    ))
```

But I get the following error,

```
String expected at position 1 in StringForm[MessageName[General, msgl], $MessageList].
Undefined message MessageName[Message, msgl] with arguments {$MessageList}
The problem may be unbounded. Specifying a value for MaxIterations greater than 5000 may improve the solution.
String expected at position 1 in StringForm[MessageName[General, msgl], $MessageList].
Undefined message MessageName[Message, msgl] with arguments {$MessageList}
String expected at position 1 in StringForm[MessageName[General, msgl], $MessageList].
Further output of MessageName[StringForm, string] will be suppressed during this calculation.
The problem may be unbounded. Specifying a value for MaxIterations greater than 5000 may improve the solution.
String expected at position 1 in StringForm[MessageName[General, msgl], $MessageList].
Undefined message MessageName[Message, msgl] with arguments {$MessageList}
The problem may be unbounded. Specifying a value for MaxIterations greater than 5000 may improve the solution.
String expected at position 1 in StringForm[MessageName[General, msgl], $MessageList].
Undefined message MessageName[Message, msgl] with arguments {$MessageList}
String expected at position 1 in StringForm[MessageName[General, msgl], $MessageList].
Further output of MessageName[StringForm, string] will be suppressed during this calculation.
The problem may be unbounded. Specifying a value for MaxIterations greater than 5000 may improve the solution.
```

Could you please suggest how this can be fixed? As shown below there was no problem in running the same expressions in MMA notebook.

Comment: What is the exact question here?

Comment: @user5601 How to establish Python Mathematica interface

Comment: You may use Mathematica from Python. How to proceed is described her: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflowguide/UsingTheWolframClientLibraryForPython.html

Comment: @DanielHuber Thank you, could you please have a look at my edit?

Comment: An example is shown in: "https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/EvaluateAWolframLanguageExpressionFromPython.html" under heading "2": "session.evaluate(wlexpr('Map[#^2 &, Range[5]]'))". The MMA expression is: "Map[#^2 &, Range[5]]"

Comment: @DanielHuber Thank you. I think I am confused here because "Map[#^2 &, Range[5]]" is a single expression and it is not clear to me how the multiline MMA expression presented above has to be inserted in `session.evaluate(wlexpr(''))`

Comment: You can include a multiline (better multi statement) expression in the command string by joining the statements by ";". E.g. 'a=1;b=2;c=3;a+b+c' and then call: session.evaluate(wlexpr('a=1;b=2;c=3;a+b+c'))

Comment: @DanielHuber Thank you. Is there a way to improve the readability of MMA expressions by including for example a newline character after each statement in the multiline statement? Kindly check my edit2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do what you want in Mathematica.

First, using "PythonExpression" can be handy to import/export things:

```
{edges,vl,ew,vd}=ImportString[#,"PythonExpression"]&/@ {"[(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,5),(2,6),(5,6),(3,4),(3,7),(6,7),(7,8),(2,9)]",
"[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]","{(1,2):49.6,(1,3):74.4,(1,4):49.6,(2,5):37.2,(2,6):74.4,(5,6):49.6,(3,4):37.2,(3,7):24.8,(6,7):62,(7,8):37.2,(2,9):24.8}",
"{1:[75.,25.,0],2:[115.,45.,0],3:[10.,5.,0],4:[45.,0,0],5:[90.,60.,0],6:[45.,55.,0],7:[0,25.,0],8:[10.,50.,0],9:[115.,25.,0]}"};
```

Unfortunately Graphs don't work with Associations yet, so you need lists, and edges should use symbols like `UndirectedEdge` or `DirectedEdge`:

```
edges = UndirectedEdge @@@ edges; vcoords = List @@ vd; 
ew = Normal @ KeyMap[UndirectedEdge @@ # &,ew];
g3d = Graph3D[vl, edges, VertexCoordinates -> vcoords, 
      EdgeWeight->ew, VertexLabels->Placed["Name",Center], 
      EdgeLabels->{e_:>Placed["EdgeWeight",Center]}, VertexSize->.5, BaseStyle->16]
```

[image]

Your computation almost worked, but you needed to make the edges into rules:

```
vars3d = Array[Through[{x, y, z}@#] &, Length@vd];
\[Lambda] = 1/100.; lbnd = 0; ubnd = 500;
obj3d = Total[(Norm[vars3d[[First@#]] - vars3d[[Last@#]]] - # /. (Rule @@@ ew))^2 & /@ EdgeList[g3d]] + \[Lambda] * Total[Norm /@ (vars3d - Values@vd)];
solution3d = Last @ Minimize[{obj3d, And @@ Thread[lbnd <= Join @@ vars3d <= ubnd]}, Join @@ vars3d]
```

Then it works fine:

```
edgeLengths3d = # -> Norm[vars3d[[First@#]] - vars3d[[Last@#]]] /. 
     solution3d & /@ EdgeList[g3d];
ResourceFunction["PrettyGrid"][{#, # /. ew, # /. edgeLengths3d} & /@ 
  EdgeList[g3d],  "ColumnHeadings" -> {"edge", "EdgeWeight", "Edge Length"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is really really helpful. I'm afraid it's still not clear to me know these Mathematica expressions have to be evaluated from Python. I've installed `wolframclient` in python and did `from wolframclient.evaluation import WolframLanguageSession
session = WolframLanguageSession()`

Comment: Could you please have a look at my edit?

Comment: I do not think this will work. But you can join the different strings into one.

Comment: @DanielHuber Thank you,  but I still don't understand how to introduce line breaks. If I introduce a line break it automatically changes to different strings.

Comment: @Natasha Does the following do what you want? str = "a=2;";
str = str <> "b=3;";
str = str <> "a*b";
ExternalEvaluate["Python", str]

Comment: @DanielHuber Should I include `ExternalEvaluate["Python", str] ` in my python script?

Comment: @DanielHuber Unfortunately, I don't understand how `str = str <> "a*b";` works. Is it used for joining two strings?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I was mistaken and did not remember that you want to use MMA from Python and not the other way round. ExternalEvaluate["Python", str] is a MMA command, not Python.

How to give MMA input from Python  is described here: "https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/EvaluateAWolframLanguageExpressionFromPython.html".

After starting Python, you execute in Python:

```py
from wolframclient.evaluation import WolframLanguageSession

session = WolframLanguageSession()

from wolframclient.language import wlexpr

session.evaluate(wlexpr('myCommandString'))
```

where myCommandString is the string with your Mathematica statements. E.g. in Python:

```py
myCommandString="a=1;b=2;a+b"
```

Or if you want this on several lines:

```py
myCommandString="a=1;"

myCommandString=myCommandString+"b=2;"

myCommandString=myCommandString+"a+b"
```

hope this helps.

Comment: I'm afraid this may not work https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframClientForPython/issues/24. I will give it a try. The above approach appears to be straightforward though - loading the contents from an m file. I think the only problem now is to figure out how to pass the python data types as input

Comment: Try to give ONE string to evaluate not several.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a block of code spanning on multiple lines, it might be useful to put it in a .m file, and `Get` the file from python. Here is a example:

First create a file and write the Wolfram Language code you'd like to evaluate in it. Let's call the file `/tmp/test.m`.

Now in Python:

```python
from wolframclient.evaluation import WolframLanguageSession
from wolframclient.language import wl

# important note: the session is automatically closed.
with WolframLanguageSession() as s:
    s.evaluate(wl.Get('/tmp/test.m'))
```

Don't forget to close `WolframLanguageSession` otherwise you'll get orphan kernels (more info [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/WolframClientForPython/docpages/basic_usages.html#session-management)).

As you can see the evaluation step now fits in one line. You are free to update your code in your favorite editor. That's exactly what I did with your initial code, I just added two missing semicolons, and exported the result as performed later on.

Here is the my `/tmp/test.m` file:

````
edges = {1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 4, 2 <-> 5, 2 <-> 6, 5 <-> 6, 
   3 <-> 4, 3 <-> 7, 6 <-> 7, 7 <-> 8, 2 <-> 9};

vd = {{75., 25., 0}, {115., 45., 0}, {10., 5., 0}, {45., 0, 0}, {90., 
    60., 0}, {45., 55., 0}, {0, 25., 0}, {10., 50., 0}, {115., 25., 
    0}};

vl = Range[Length@vd];

vcoords = MapIndexed[#2[[1]] -> # &, vd];
ew = {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2 -> 49.6, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3 -> 74.4, 
  1 \[UndirectedEdge] 4 -> 49.6, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 5 -> 37.2, 
  2 \[UndirectedEdge] 6 -> 74.4, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 6 -> 49.6, 
  3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4 -> 37.2, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 7 -> 24.8, 
  6 \[UndirectedEdge] 7 -> 62, 7 \[UndirectedEdge] 8 -> 37.2, 
  2 \[UndirectedEdge] 9 -> 24.8};

g3d = Graph3D[vl, edges, VertexCoordinates -> vcoords, 
  EdgeWeight -> ew, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
  EdgeLabels -> {e_ :> Placed["EdgeWeight", Center]}, 
  VertexSize -> .3, VertexStyle -> Red];
vars3d = Array[Through[{x, y, z}@#] &, Length@vd];

\[Lambda] = 1/100.;

obj3d = Total[(Norm[vars3d[[First@#]] - vars3d[[Last@#]]] - # /. 
         ew)^2 & /@ EdgeList[g3d]] + \[Lambda] Total[
     Norm /@ (vars3d - vd)];

lbnd = 0;
ubnd = 500;

solution3d = 
  Last@Minimize[{obj3d, 
     And @@ Thread[lbnd <= Join @@ vars3d <= ubnd]}, Join @@ vars3d];

edgeLengths3d = # -> Norm[vars3d[[First@#]] - vars3d[[Last@#]]] /. 
     solution3d & /@ EdgeList[g3d];

z1 = Values[solution3d] // Partition[#, 3] &;
Export["/tmp/result.txt", z1, "Table"];
```
````

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helps! Could you please let me know how to pass input arguments to .m file? The variables `edges`, `vd`, `ew` and `vl` are python data types. Above, it was suggested to do `{edges,vl,ew,vd}=ImportString[#,"PythonExpression"]&/@ {"[(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,5),(2,6),(5,6),(3,4),(3,7),(6,7),(7,8),(2,9)]",
"[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]","{(1,2):49.6,(1,3):74.4,(1,4):49.6,(2,5):37.2,(2,6):74.4,(5,6):49.6,(3,4):37.2,(3,7):24.8,(6,7):62,(7,8):37.2,(2,9):24.8}",
"{1:[75.,25.,0],2:[115.,45.,0],3:[10.,5.,0],4:[45.,0,0],5:[90.,60.,0],6:[45.,55.,0],7:[0,25.,0],8:[10.,50.,0],9:[115.,25.,0]}"};`

Comment: But I am not sure how to pass the input arguments from my python script for evaluating MMA expressions.

Comment: You can't really pass argument to a .m file, but you can declare functions in such a file and once you `Get` it, the functions become available in python as well. Say you have declared a WL function `solution3d[...] := (...)`, you can call it from python using:
first `from wolframclient.language import Global` followed by `s.evaluate(Global.solution3d(edge, vd, vl, ed))`

Also note that a lot of python native types are automatically converted to WL counterpart. e.g: tuple `(1,2)` becomes a list `{1, 2}`, etc.

Comment: Ahh, that's a wonderful suggestion. If you don't mind could you please show how to declare a WL function that accepts arguments in the solution you have posted? I'm new to MMA :(

Comment: Like this :  `solution3d = wl.Get('test.m')
 s.evaluate(Global.solution3d(edges, vd, vl, ew)) `? [cross-posted](https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframClientForPython/issues/24#issuecomment-699788579)