# Problem while running Mathematica code from Python using wolframclient library

Tags: functions, function-construction, python, wolfram-client

This is a follow up to my previous post [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230518/how-to-use-mathematica-from-python)

I am trying to  run a function from Python using `wolframclient`. The input arguments are passed from Python as Python datatypes.

The following is saved in test.m file (for Mathematica script please [check](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/230570/58343))

```
solutioncheck[edges_, vd_, vl_, ew_] := (

    edges = UndirectedEdge @@@ edges; vcoords = List @@ vd;
    ew = Normal @ KeyMap[UndirectedEdge @@ # &,ew];

    g3d = Graph3D[vl, edges, VertexCoordinates -> vcoords, EdgeWeight->ew, VertexLabels->Placed["Name",Center],
    EdgeLabels->{e_:>Placed["EdgeWeight",Center]}, VertexSize->.5, BaseStyle->16];


    vars3d = Array[Through[{x, y, z}@#] &, Length@vd];
    \[Lambda] = 1/100.; lbnd = 0; ubnd = 500;

    obj3d = Total[(Norm[vars3d[[First@#]] - vars3d[[Last@#]]] - # /. (Rule @@@ ew))^2 & /@ EdgeList[g3d]] + \[Lambda] * Total[Norm /@ (vars3d - Values@vd)];
    solution3d = Last @ Minimize[{obj3d, And @@ Thread[lbnd <= Join @@ vars3d <= ubnd]}, Join @@ vars3d];

    edgeLengths3d = # -> Norm[vars3d[[First@#]] - vars3d[[Last@#]]] /.solution3d & /@ EdgeList[g3d];
    ResourceFunction["PrettyGrid"][{#, # /. ew, # /. edgeLengths3d} & /@EdgeList[g3d],  "ColumnHeadings" -> {"edge", "EdgeWeight", "Edge Length"}];

    z1 = Values[solution3d] // Partition[#, 3] &;

    theFile = File["result.txt"];

    Export[theFile, z1, "Table"];
)
```

Using `wolframclient` library in Python, I tried

```
    from wolframclient.evaluation import WolframLanguageSession
    from wolframclient.language import wl, wlexpr, Global

    session = WolframLanguageSession()

    edges = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (5, 6), (3, 4), (3, 7), (6, 7), (7, 8), (2, 9)]
    vl = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    ew = {(1, 2): 49.6, (1, 3): 74.4, (1, 4): 49.6, (2, 5): 37.2, (2, 6): 74.4, (5, 6): 49.6, (3, 4): 37.2, (3, 7): 24.8, (6, 7): 62, (7, 8): 37.2, (2, 9): 24.8}
    vd = {1: [75., 25., 0], 2: [115., 45., 0], 3: [10., 5., 0], 4: [45., 0, 0], 5: [90., 60., 0], 6: [45., 55., 0], 7: [0, 25., 0], 8: [10., 50., 0], 9: [115., 25., 0]}
    with WolframLanguageSession() as s:
        s.evaluate(wl.Get('test.m'))
        s.evaluate(Global.solutioncheck(edges, vd, vl, ew))
```

I am not sure what's wrong in the above, the run doesn't terminate.

Could someone please look into this?

EDIT:
For some reason, I think the graph object isn't created

I get the following message when I Print(ew)

```
A graph object is expected at position 1 in EdgeList[Power[Plus[Times[-1, g3d], Norm[Plus[Part[{{x[1], y[1], z[1]}, {x[2], y[2], z[2]}, {x[3], y[3], z[3]}, {x[4], y[4], z[4]}, {x[5], y[5], z[5]}, {x[6], y[6], z[6]}, {x[7], y[7], z[7]}, {x[8], y[8], z[8]}, {x[9], y[9], z[9]}}, First[g3d]], Times[-1, Part[{{x[1], y[1], z[1]}, {x[2], y[2], z[2]}, {x[3], y[3], z[3]}, {x[4], y[4], z[4]}, {x[5], y[5], z[5]}, {x[6], y[6], z[6]}, {x[7], y[7], z[7]}, {x[8], y[8], z[8]}, {x[9], y[9], z[9]}}, Last[g3d]]]]]], 2]].
Tag Times in Times[500, obj3d, Print] is Protected.
Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in First[g3d].
The expression First[g3d] cannot be used as a part specification.
Further output of MessageName[Part, pkspec1] will be suppressed during this calculation.
Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Last[g3d].
The expression Last[g3d] cannot be used as a part specification.
The expression First[g3d] cannot be used as a part specification.
The expression Last[g3d] cannot be used as a part specification.
A graph object is expected at position 1 in EdgeList[g3d -> Norm[Plus[Part[{{250, 250, 250}, {250, 250, 250}, {250, 250, 250}, {250, 250, 250}, {250, 250, 250}, {250, 250, 250}, {250, 250, 250}, {250, 250, 250}, {250, 250, 250}}, First[g3d]], Times[-1, Part[{{250, 250, 250}, {250, 250, 250}, {250, 250, 250}, {250, 250, 250}, {250, 250, 250}, {250, 250, 250}, {250, 250, 250}, {250, 250, 250}, {250, 250, 250}}, Last[g3d]]]]]].
Tag Times in Times[edgeLengths3d, Print, {x[1] -> 250, y[1] -> 250, z[1] -> 250, x[2] -> 250, y[2] -> 250, z[2] -> 250, x[3] -> 250, y[3] -> 250, z[3] -> 250, x[4] -> 250, y[4] -> 250, z[4] -> 250, x[5] -> 250, y[5] -> 250, z[5] -> 250, x[6] -> 250, y[6] -> 250, z[6] -> 250, x[7] -> 250, y[7] -> 250, z[7] -> 250, x[8] -> 250, y[8] -> 250, z[8] -> 250, x[9] -> 250, y[9] -> 250, z[9] -> 250}] is Protected.
{edgeLengths3d} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.
A graph object is expected at position 1 in EdgeList[{g3d, g3d, ReplaceAll[g3d, edgeLengths3d]}].
Further output of MessageName[EdgeList, graph] will be suppressed during this calculation.
A graph object is expected at position 1 in EdgeList[{Item[edge, Alignment -> {Center, Baseline}, BaseStyle -> Bold, ItemSize -> {Automatic, 1.5}], Item[EdgeWeight, Alignment -> {Center, Baseline}, BaseStyle -> Bold, ItemSize -> {Automatic, 1.5}], Item[Edge Length, Alignment -> {Center, Baseline}, BaseStyle -> Bold, ItemSize -> {Automatic, 1.5}]}, {g3d, g3d, ReplaceAll[g3d, edgeLengths3d]}].
```

Comment: Add some Prints to your .m file. It then produces some output. `First argument ... is not a string`. Your `edges, vd ,vl, ew` are already in list/association forms at the point of calling the function so you don't need `ImportString` and you can remove the entire line `{edges,vl,ew,vd}=ImportString[#,"PythonExpression"]&/@{edges,vl,ew,vd};`.

Comment: Your Mathematica code doesn't really make sense. You have `solution3d ` appearing on a line starting with `edgeLengths3d  = ...` as a replacement rule. Yet you haven't even defined solution3d yet, which appears later on the line starting `solution3d = Last @ Minimize[ ... `. Also it has the same name as the function it is in, so you should change that. Also `edgeLengths3d` gets defined twice.

Comment: @flinty Thanks a lot, I have made the corrections. The code doesn't terminate yet

Comment: @flinty Thanks a lot, I have made the corrections. An output could be generated but there are issues. The output is not right. Please check my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have rewritten your code somewhat. It now completes in python and it works in Mathematica. Please tell me if the outputs are reasonable.

```
solution3d[edges_, vd_, vl_, ew_] := Module[{
   uedges = UndirectedEdge @@@ edges,
   vcoords = List @@ vd,
   ew2 = KeyMap[UndirectedEdge @@ # &, ew],
   vars3d, \[Lambda], lbnd, ubnd, obj3d, err, sol, edgeLengths3d},

  \[Lambda] = 1/100.; lbnd = 0; ubnd = 500;
  vars3d = Array[Through[{x, y, z}@#] &, Length@vd];
  
  obj3d = Total[
   (EuclideanDistance[vars3d[[First[#]]], vars3d[[Last[#]]]] - ew2[#])^2 & /@ Keys[ew2]
  ] + \[Lambda]*Total[
    MapThread[EuclideanDistance[#1, #2] &, {vars3d, Values[vd]}]
  ];

  {err, sol} = Quiet[
    NMinimize[{obj3d, And @@ Thread[lbnd <= Join @@ vars3d <= ubnd]}, Flatten[vars3d]]
  ];

  edgeLengths3d = # -> EuclideanDistance[
    vars3d[[First@#]], vars3d[[Last@#]]
  ] /. sol & /@ Keys[ew2];

  Export["result.txt", Partition[Values[sol], 3], "Table"];
  Return[<|"Error" -> err, "Solution" -> sol, "EdgeLengths" -> edgeLengths3d|>];
]

(* test it out *)
edges = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 5}, {2, 6}, {5, 6}, {3, 4}, {3, 7}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}, {2, 9}};
vl = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
ew = <|{1, 2} -> 49.6, {1, 3} -> 74.4, {1, 4} -> 49.6, {2, 5} -> 37.2, {2, 6} -> 74.4, {5, 6} -> 49.6, {3, 4} -> 37.2, {3, 7} -> 24.8, {6, 7} -> 62, {7, 8} -> 37.2, {2, 9} -> 24.8|>;
vd = <|1 -> {75., 25., 0}, 2 -> {115., 45., 0}, 3 -> {10., 5., 0}, 4 -> {45., 0, 0}, 5 -> {90., 60., 0}, 6 -> {45., 55., 0}, 7 -> {0, 25., 0}, 8 -> {10., 50., 0}, 9 -> {115., 25., 0}|>;

solution3d[edges, vd, vl, ew]

(* result: *)
<|"Error" -> 0.880709, 
 "Solution" -> {x[1] -> 77.6922, y[1] -> 22.5731, z[1] -> 0.00182091, 
   x[2] -> 121.007, y[2] -> 46.7324, z[2] -> 0.000518892, 
   x[3] -> 6.80262, y[3] -> 0., z[3] -> 7.88157*10^-7, x[4] -> 28.67, 
   y[4] -> 30.0881, z[4] -> 0.0677469, x[5] -> 95.0311, 
   y[5] -> 73.3522, z[5] -> 0.166862, x[6] -> 47.5991, 
   y[6] -> 58.8693, z[6] -> 2.92651*10^-6, x[7] -> 0., y[7] -> 20.865,
    z[7] -> 11.5351, x[8] -> 11.3995, y[8] -> 54.3391, 
   z[8] -> 3.5958*10^-6, x[9] -> 114.484, y[9] -> 22.8077, 
   z[9] -> 0.029674}, 
 "EdgeLengths" -> {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2 -> 49.5968, 
   1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3 -> 74.3967, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 4 -> 49.595, 
   2 \[UndirectedEdge] 5 -> 37.194, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 6 -> 74.4045, 
   5 \[UndirectedEdge] 6 -> 49.5941, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4 -> 37.1952,
    3 \[UndirectedEdge] 7 -> 24.7928, 
   6 \[UndirectedEdge] 7 -> 61.9923, 7 \[UndirectedEdge] 8 -> 37.1957,
    2 \[UndirectedEdge] 9 -> 24.798}|>
```

As before, `solution3d` exports its results but also returns an `Association` which you can access from python as a dictionary:

```python
from wolframclient.evaluation import WolframLanguageSession
from wolframclient.language import wl, wlexpr, Global

session = WolframLanguageSession()

edges = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (5, 6), (3, 4), (3, 7), (6, 7), (7, 8), (2, 9)]
vl = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
ew = {(1, 2): 49.6, (1, 3): 74.4, (1, 4): 49.6, (2, 5): 37.2, (2, 6): 74.4, (5, 6): 49.6, (3, 4): 37.2, (3, 7): 24.8, (6, 7): 62, (7, 8): 37.2, (2, 9): 24.8}
vd = {1: [75., 25., 0], 2: [115., 45., 0], 3: [10., 5., 0], 4: [45., 0, 0], 5: [90., 60., 0], 6: [45., 55., 0], 7: [0, 25., 0], 8: [10., 50., 0], 9: [115., 25., 0]}
with WolframLanguageSession() as s:
    s.evaluate(wl.Get('test.m'))
    result = s.evaluate(Global.solution3d(edges, vd, vl, ew))
    ## This should be a dictionary 
    ## of the form {'Error': err, 'Solution':(...), 'EdgeLengths':(...)}

    print(result)
```

Comment: Hi @flinty Thank you so much  Yes, the results are reasonable. Could you please explain why the line `g3d = Graph3D[vl, edges, VertexCoordinates -> vcoords, EdgeWeight->ew, VertexLabels->Placed["Name",Center],
    EdgeLabels->{e_:>Placed["EdgeWeight",Center]}, VertexSize->.5, BaseStyle->16];` has been removed. In Mathematica this was useful to visualize the graph network. But I am not sure why the graph object isn't working while running from Python. I would like to know if there is a way to create the graph object and visualize the network while running via wolframclient.

Comment: Because it's unnecessary inside a function unless you are returning it, which you are not. You were also suppressing the output with a semicolon so it wouldn't show up either. Also you're not going to get any visual outputs calling it from Python anyway because you can't spawn a front-end, just a headless kernel. If you want visual outputs while driving Mathematica from python, you should rasterize and export them as images.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. `If you want visual outputs while driving Mathematica from python, you should rasterize and export them as images. ` I guess this will help me in viewing the 3D graph as a 2D image. May I know if there is a way to view the 3D image? Will I be able to export as a html file and view the 3D? If it is possible, could you please provide references to some examples that show how to do this?

Comment: From Python? Use this https://plotly.com/python/v3/3d-network-graph or this https://www.idtools.com.au/3d-network-graphs-python-mplot3d-toolkit . It's a lot of work. You'd probably be better off ditching python and just doing it all from within Mathematica, but you may have other reasons for using python.

Comment: But when I pass `edges = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (5, 6), (3, 4), (3, 7), (6, 7), (7, 8), (2, 9)] vl = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] ew = {(1, 2): 49.6, (1, 3): 74.4, (1, 4): 49.6, (2, 5): 37.2, (2, 6): 74.4, (5, 6): 49.6, (3, 4): 37.2, (3, 7): 24.8, (6, 7): 62, (7, 8): 37.2, (2, 9): 24.8} vd = {1: [75., 25., 0], 2: [115., 45., 0], 3: [10., 5., 0], 4: [45., 0, 0], 5: [90., 60., 0], 6: [45., 55., 0], 7: [0, 25., 0], 8: [10., 50., 0], 9: [115., 25., 0]}` from Python the code doesn't run successfully. Could you please suggest how the input arguments have to be passed from Python?

Comment: @Natasha But it _does_ work with that input for me from python. You should copy just the function `solution3d` into _test.m_ and remove everything else, not the rest. You have to wait ~20 seconds or so for your test.py to finish executing. What problem are you experiencing? I am using Python 3.8.3 and Mathematica 12.1.1.0

Comment: Messages displayed in command line [here](https://github.com/DeepaMahm/misc/blob/master/out.txt), call [here](https://github.com/DeepaMahm/misc/blob/master/call.py) and function [here](https://github.com/DeepaMahm/misc/blob/master/test.m) Could you please have a  look?

Comment: You have `Print` in there but that first `Tag Times...` error means you've not ended each Print with a semicolon. Are you sure you've actually replaced your test.m file with my code above, or have you modified it?

Comment: What is this syntax? `Print(uedges)` and `Print(ew2)`.  That's not correct Mathematica syntax. You should write `Print[uedges];` and `Print[ew2];` with brackets and semicolons, not parentheses.

Comment: Ahh, that was my mistake. I failed to notice the square brackets in MMA syntax. The output is written successfully now. But from what I see using Print[] doesn't display the output in python . I'm not sure if there is a way to print these outputs in Python terminal. Also, could you please explain why `solution3d = Last @ Minimize[{obj3d, And @@ Thread[lbnd <= Join @@ vars3d <= ubnd]}, Join @@ vars3d];` was changed to NMinimize ? Could you please suggest how to return `err` while using `solution3d = Last @ Minimize[{obj3d, And @@ Thread[lbnd <= Join @@ vars3d <= ubnd]}, Join @@ vars3d];` ?

Comment: You should be using `NMinimize` because it's a numerical problem. The error is already returned - note that I return an association: `Return[<|"Error" -> err, "Solution" -> sol, "EdgeLengths" -> edgeLengths3d|>];`. From **Python** please try this: `result = s.evaluate(Global.solution3d(edges, vd, vl, ew))
    print(result)`  and you will see that `result` contains a dictionary where you can get the err like this: `result["Error"]`